# Check if input field contains @ character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

Im trying to check if my input field contains an @ sign in it

so here is what i have and its not working:

```
$( "#Button" ).click(function() {
    if ($('#email:contains("@")')) {

    } else { 
        $('#email').text('Wrong');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xJtAV/70/

Any ideas?

Comment: A simple example http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/t1900bpa/

Answer (score 5):

`:contains()` returns a jQuery object matching the criteria. It does not match value.

Use `indexOf()` over `.val()`,

```
if ($('#email').val().indexOf('@') > -1) {
```

Also, in your `else{}`, use `.val()` as text() does not set any value.

```
$('#email').val('Wrong');
```

But I'd suggest you use another element say `<span id="emailError">`

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJtAV/73/)**

Answer (score 4):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xJtAV/71/. The string function `indexOf()` will search any string for whatever you'd like and return the index of the first character of the first occurence...

String indexOf() docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

**JS**

```
$( "#Button" ).click(function() {

    if ($('#email').val().indexOf('@') >= 0) {
       $('#email').val('Yes! It contains an "@" symbol!');
    } else { 
        $('#email').val('No :( No "@" symbol');
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<input id="email" name="email" class="email" type="text" />
<br><br>

<div id="Button" style="height:100px; width: 150px; background-color: #000;">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, worked perfect for my need to check it the opposite way! I needed to check if an input field did not have a px in the field and if so add it.  So I just revered the >= to <= Thanks!