# Check if inputs contain #

Tags: jquery, input, each, contains, indexof

In my form I have 10-15 `input`s with same `class` *(its dynamic and made by my application for `nested_forms`)*.

*My form:*

```
<h1 id="error"></h1>
<form>

<input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][1489492164895][link]" id="maps_attributes_1489492164895_link">

<input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][7192817201001][link]" id="maps_attributes_7192817201001_link">

<input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][1701829110864][link]" id="maps_attributes_1701829110864_link">

<input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][9918271627198][link]" id="maps_attributes_9918271627198_link">

// & more

</form>
```

User will paste **links** to these `inputs` & Im trying to check if any of the links contains **#**.

[I used this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355078/check-if-input-field-contains-character), but problem is that, it only checks the first `input` and not the rest of them.

*This is what I have tried:*

```
// 1
$( "input.maps_input" ).change(function() {
  $("input.maps_input").each(function(){
    if ($('input.maps_input').val().indexOf('#') > -1) {
      $('#error').text('Has #');
    }
  });
});
```

*&*

```
//2
$("input.maps_input").each(function(){
  $( "input.maps_input" ).change(function() {
    if ($('input.maps_input').val().indexOf('#') > -1) {
      $('#error').text('Has #');
    }
  });
});
```

What is it Im doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: jQuery selectors can be **chained**. It's in fact one of the killer features that helped to make it so popular.

Comment: in your //1 firstly do `$(this).val()` in your `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks @BhavikPatel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly this may solve your issue

```js
$('body').on('change', "input.maps_input", function() {
  if ($(this).val().indexOf('#') > -1) {
    $('#error').text('Has #');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="error"></h1>
<form>
  <input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][1489492164895][link]" id="maps_attributes_1489492164895_link">
  <input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][7192817201001][link]" id="maps_attributes_7192817201001_link">
  <input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][1701829110864][link]" id="maps_attributes_1701829110864_link">
  <input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][9918271627198][link]" id="maps_attributes_9918271627198_link"> // & more
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Samuel :)

Comment: I will, Stackoverflow, doesnt let me until 3 min haha

Answer (score 3):

Samuel code will work, i would like to add explanation why so that you understand what was wrong,

inside your .each loop you where trying to access the value using
$('input.maps_input').val() , and since there are multiple objects so only the first is being used every time, so inside the jquery.each it is always better to use $(this) to access the exact same item you are iterating over

Answer (score 0):

use `focusout` .

```js
$("input.maps_input").focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val().indexOf('#') > -1) {
        $('#error').text('Has #');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="error"></h1>
<form>
  <input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][1489492164895][link]" id="maps_attributes_1489492164895_link">
  <input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][7192817201001][link]" id="maps_attributes_7192817201001_link">
  <input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][1701829110864][link]" id="maps_attributes_1701829110864_link">
  <input class="maps_input" type="text" name="map[maps_attributes][9918271627198][link]" id="maps_attributes_9918271627198_link"> // & more
</form>
```